# Access more data from flare.json for d3.tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm basicaly working with [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025).

Now, the flare.json is something like

```
{ "name": "flare", "children": [  {   "name": "analytics",   "children": [    {     "name": "cluster",...
```

I need more information to be displayed, not just the name so after fetching the data I have something like.

```
{ "name": "John Smith", "Age": "20", "Country": "Canada", "children": [  {  //and so on
```

All nodes will have more fields than just "name", let's say 3 or 4 items in total.

The code part for appending the data is

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
  .attr("dy", 3.5)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I've tryed `return d.name + ' - ' + d.age;});` but it just works on the root node. On all the children it says the name properly but instead of the Age.Text it says `[object Object]`

Basicaly I need to access not just the "name" from the flare.json file but a few more items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This indicates that your children don't have the correct `age` property. Have you verified that it is present everywhere you want to use it?

Comment: "age":"xx" is present in every children/node. Is it what you're asking?

Comment: Yes. In that case it should work fine. It certainly works fine for me with the `size` attribute, see http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/6554125

Comment: Indeed! maybe it's the `(d.size ? " " + d.size : "")` which I didn't use. Please feel free to answer it that way so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with the `size` attribute that is already present in the data. See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/6554125) for an example. What I've done is change the `.text` to

```
.text(function(d) { return d.name + (d.size ? " " + d.size : ""); });
```

which will display the size information if it is present.